# Buck Regulator Explosions

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, buck

I'm trying to use a Semtech 5V 3A buck regulator, and there is obviously something wrong with the circuit, because whenever I try to pull current from it, the IC catches fire...

I've done buck regulators before and the schematic looks fine to me, but maybe I'm missing something obvious. I depopulated U15 and hooked up resistors to the output to draw current, and when ~100mA were being drawn the voltage started to drop until eventually the regulator caught fire. Any thoughts on causes?

[image: Buck Regulator Schematic]

Below are the different parts with digikey part #s:

- U2: TS30013-M050QFNRCT-ND
- L2: SRN6045TA-4R7MCT-ND
- C4: 1276-1104-1-ND
- C6, C8: 1276-6504-1-ND
- C2: 1276-6736-1-nd

The full project can be found here: https://github.com/UWARG/ZeroPilot-HW/releases

Thanks!

**EDIT**: Below is a screen shot of the pcb layout. You can also look at the github link if you are familiar with KiCad.

[image]

**EDIT #2**: Below is an oscilloscope screenshot of the input on CH2 and output on CH1 with a 200 Ohm load (25mA). There isn't substantial noise for either signal at any frequency, no matter how much I zoomed in or out. As you can see, the output voltage has dipped to under 5V under a 25mA load.

[image]

5V_INT_OUT node with no load:

[image]

5V_INT_OUT node as it started to smoke:

[image]

Hopefully those oscilliscope images help, I managed to catch one of the screenshots half way through the buck regulator failing, using a 200mA load.

Comment: I have never seen an IC actually catching fire. Maybe some smoke, but not fire. Are you sure it's a genuine part?

Comment: We need to see your PCB layout. Do you have a ground plane connected to the exposed metal on the bottom of the part? Is the input source stiff enough? (The schematic says VBATT so I assume it's some form of battery, but hey). Is the duty cycle on the switching node stable? Did you try fitting the optional catch diode (DCATCH)?

Comment: I added the PCB layout. I bought it from Digi-key so I would assume the part is genuine. I was testing with VBatt = 7.5V

Comment: Stick a scope on the top of C2 and see if Vbat is still 7.5V under some load. Also, can we see a dual trace picture of both ends of C4 (**SHORT** ground leads please)?

Comment: How about a scope trace of the switching node (5V_INT_OUT) please show a compete cycle and use a **SHORT** ground clip, not one of those useless three inch bits of wire with a croc clip.

Comment: @DanMills I put a scope on 5v_INT_OUT like you suggested, see screenshots above. It looks fine to me, but as you can see by the second screenshot I blew another buck regulator while trying to get those measurements. Some destructive testing :)

Comment: OK, it looks like it's switching, so it should be soldered properly. However in the "no load" case it should go into PFM mode (since there is no load!) and only throw a pulse once in a while, not continuously. This is suspicious. Shorted output cap? Something is drawing current, or something is wrong. Check input current, check solder joints...

Comment: I assume the green is SW node, SW pin on the chip. The last shot shows PFM mode, frequency is reduced. Why didn't this happen before?... I wonder. This could also be a current or temperature limit triggering. Maybe inductor saturation? Anyway, check input current with ammeter, it should be very low when output is unloaded.

Comment: Input current at no load is 10mA, input current at 200mA load is ~250mA.

Comment: Does it blow at no load or at 200mA load? Input power is 7V5x250mA=1.875W, output power is 5Vx200mA=1W so there is 0.875W going "somewhere" then creating smoke...

Answer (score 2):

Check C4 and the connections around it carefully.  This sounds like the integrated switch FET is ending up in linear mode, and therefore dissipating a lot of power.  C4 is part of the charge pump that creates the gate voltage for this internal N-channel FET.  If this charge pump is not working, then the FET can't be fully turned on.

I once accidentally connected the charge pump cap to the wrong side of the inductor, and got similar symptoms.  Mine weren't quite as spectacular, but the output voltage was regulated at low currents, and the chip got hot.

### Added

When debugging a switching power supply, the first thing to do is to look at the waveform going into the inductor.  That is very diagnostic, and various subtle things can be seen from its details.

Show us the waveform over at least one complete pulse with a relatively light load.  That will tell us a lot.  When capturing this trace, make sure to ground the scope probe properly to a solid ground node near the switching chip.

### Scope trace

[image]

This is a rather annoying scope trace.  You've got plenty of vertical room, yet have the gain set to 5 V/div.  There is very little detail per cycle because there are too many cycles on the screen.  And the worst is that the zero volt are in random places not lined up with a division, making it more work than necessary to see the voltage.

If you want someone to spend their free time looking at your problem, show some respect, by taking some care and paying attention to the details.

I'm outta here.

Comment: "*Check the C4*". That's some high quality explosive.

Comment: I checked and don't see anything wrong with it. C4 is connected just as the buck regulator datasheet says to, and it looks to be the correct value. The capacitor I used is 0.022µF ±10% 50V Ceramic Capacitor X7R 0603. The data sheet asks for 15-200nF capacitor, so this should be fine.

Comment: What is VBat? The part specified 4.5V minimum and I would not be surprised to see funky behaviour if you are pushing that limit.  The layout has significant plane area on the switching node, usually not a great idea. Is the inductor end of C4 actually soldered, I ask because it has no thermal relief, so if reflowed it may be dry, same for the Gnd end of C2 and the switching nodes on the chip (You might want to look into thermals, they make soldering easier and more reliable).

Comment: I was testing Vbatt = 7.5V using a bench power supply. I just took a look under the microscope and with a multimeter and the solder joint for the inductor and C4 look fine. Why is a large area on the switching node a bad idea?

Comment: It forms a capacitor with the ground plane which creates a resonance which can be somewhere you really wish it wasn't, if you end up with too much Q you can even blow the sand due to excessive ringing on this node.

Comment: See edit for oscilliscope capture

Comment: In term of the scope trace, I added the measurements at the bottom of the scope image. The horizontal scale is a bit too wide, but I think you can still get a pretty good view of the signal. The reason they were at 5V/V is so I could see both signals on the screen at the same time without overlap. I understand that some of the settings might not be ideal, but everyone uses oscilloscopes a little differently and you can still get most of the information from the screenshot. Thanks for the help.